# Joomla - Create session variable from checkbox with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, joomla

I'm trying to create a session variable joomla style with ajax when checkboxes are selected. Here is my code in the select_thumb.ajax.php file:

```
$_SESSION['ss'] = $value;
$response = $_SESSION['ss'];
echo $response;

}
exit;
// Get db connection
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
//create new query object
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

//Prepare insert query
$query
    ->insert($db->valueChbx('download_variable'))

// Set the query using populated query object and execute it.
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
?>
```

Here is my HTML for the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="thumbselect" name="valueChbx" class="checkbox" value="/import/images/'+data[i]['filename']+'">';
```

I haven't coded the ajax through javascript yet because I'm wondering if i should use onFocus? There could be multiple checkboxes selected. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use PHP's default session variable in Joomla application use its native factory for that.

Set a session variable

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('name', "value");
```

Get a session variable

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->get('name');
```

[more](https://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getSession) .

hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you for your response; however, this really doesn't answer my entire question. I'm familiar with Joomla's method here but it lacks better explanation to pull a value from a checkbox via AJAX request.

Comment: jQuery("#thumbselect").val() will get the value of checkbox, if you want to check the status of checkbox then it should be , jQuery("#thumbselect").is(':checked');

Comment: Anybody able to piece some code together for me? I'm pretty sure i can use the document.GetElementById() method to retrieve the checkbox value. I just need to get into the Session method for Joomla probably following your example above.